# Given that $0<r<n$ and r is much smaller than n, show that $\frac{n-r}{n} \approx e^{\frac{-r}{n}}$

Tags: approximation

I tried to solve this problem; and I looked at the answer. It said that $e^{\frac{-r}{n}} =\sum_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{(\frac{-r}{n})^k}{k!}}\approx 1-\frac{r}{n} $  I can't under stand the summation approximation.

Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: Since $r$ is much smaller than $n$, the higher order terms of $\frac{r}{n}$ are ignored, yielding the result

Comment: They just keep the term with $k=0$, which is $1$, and the term with $k=1$, which is $-r/n$. They assume that for higher powers $(r/n)^k <<1$

Comment: Thank you very much for you guys' replies. 

This seems quite difficult for me to understand. Since I thought $\frac{-r}{n} <<1 $ also. Why don't we just abandon all the terms and leave only '1'.

Comment: The approximation is getting worse, obviously. If $r$ is the interest rate, $r$ is near $0$. Then $\frac{r}{n}$ is becomes very fast small if it is raised to power.

Comment: @callculus Thank you. May I ask whether it is a normal practice to abandon the terms with ''power' when doing approximation? Thank you so much, and sorry for any inconvenience causedd.

Comment: Sure, especially if the term which is raised to power is near $0$.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3127746/144421) for such an approximation. Here the interest rate plays a role as well.

Comment: thank you very much